# Selecting multiple images with JS/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Gridster for webpage.The widgets have images on it.These images can be added and deleted with `+` and `X` button.

**Current State**

When I press `+` a modal opens in which user can  multiple images and on clicking `Add Image` those images get added on widgets.This part works fine.

When an image is clicked `class = "preset"` is added to the div in which the image is present.This class highlights the selected image.

When user again clicks the same image the class is removed from that image.

I also have added a `removeclass` function(which removes the class from all div's in which images are there)  which is invoked when `Add Image` is clicked or modal is closed with `close` button or a `X` button on top right of modal

**The problem**

The code behaves in expected way when I add images for first time.

When I add images for second time(in the same widget or any other widget) the images are not getting highlighted/selected at all but if I click `Add Image` button previous images get added to a widget.

When I just close it from second time and again click the `+` button to add images for third time the output is as expected(images get highlighted, same images get added on the widget etc)

To summarize it the code works fine for 1, 3, 5 ..... time but weird on 2, 4, 6 ...... time

Also when I see the output

```
 console.log("In remove");
 console.log(selectedImageSRC);
```

and

```
console.log("In add");
 console.log(selectedImageSRC);
```

I found it expected when I am running the code for 1, 3, 5 ..... time.

But it is weird for 2, 4, 5 time.

**Wierdness which I found in the console**

`if` and `else` both of them is executed which is a part of function one below

My Function 1

```
    //Adding Images from Modal
    var parentLI;
    var selectedImageSRC = "";

   $(document).on("click", ".addmorebrands", function() {
        parentLI = $(this).closest('li');
        $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show');
        $('#exampleModalCenter img').click(function(){
        parentdiv = $(this).closest('div.outerdiv');
        if (parentdiv.hasClass('preselect')) {                     //this if is executed in 2, 4, 5 time of code 

            parentdiv.removeClass('preselect');
            selectedImageSRC = selectedImageSRC.replace($(this).attr('src'),"");
            selectedImageSRC = trimChar(selectedImageSRC, ',');
            selectedImageSRC = (selectedImageSRC.replace(/,,/g , ","));
            console.log("In remove");
            console.log(selectedImageSRC);
            console.log("Parent Div in remove");
            console.log(parentdiv);
        }else {    //at same time (2, 4, 6 time of code execution) this else also get executed

            parentdiv.addClass('preselect');

            if (selectedImageSRC === '') {

                selectedImageSRC += $(this).attr('src');

            } else {

                selectedImageSRC += ',' + $(this).attr('src');
            }

            console.log("In add");
            console.log(selectedImageSRC);
            console.log("Parent Div in Add");
            console.log(parentdiv);
        }     


        })    



    });
```

My function 2

```
 $('#add-image').click(function(){

        console.log("In add image");
        console.log(selectedImageSRC);
        var multipleImageSRC = "";
        multipleImageSRC = selectedImageSRC.split(',');
        console.log("Splitted Images");
        console.log(multipleImageSRC);
        var multipleImages = "";
        for(var j = 0; j < multipleImageSRC.length; j++) {
            {% load static %}
            multipleImages += '<div class="imagewrap"><img class="images" src="'+multipleImageSRC[j]+'" title="Manual Addition"> <input type="button" class="removediv" value="X" /></div>'
            console.log("Multiple Images SRC");
            console.log(multipleImages);
        }


        parentLI.append(multipleImages);



        var imageNameValue = parentLI.children('.imagenames').val();
        var imageTitleValue = parentLI.children('.hoverinformation').val();

        //Loop for Updating Textarea with ImageNames
        var imageNameInTextarea = "";
        for (var j = 0; j < multipleImageSRC.length; j++) {

            imageNameInTextarea += multipleImageSRC[j].replace("/static/images/brands/","") + ",";

        }

        //To remove last ',' after the names
        imageNameInTextarea = trimChar(imageNameInTextarea, ',');
        console.log(imageNameInTextarea);

        //Loop calculating lenght of number of images added and correspondingly putting "Manual Addition"

        manualAddition = "";

        for (var j = 0; j < multipleImageSRC.length; j++) {

            manualAddition += "Manual Addition" + ",";

        }

        //To remove last ',' after the names
        manualAddition = trimChar(manualAddition, ',');

        console.log("Manual Textarea");
        console.log(manualAddition);

        if (imageNameValue === '') {
            parentLI.children('.imagenames').val(imageNameInTextarea);
        } else {
            parentLI.children('.imagenames').val(imageNameValue + ',' + imageNameInTextarea);
        }


        if (imageTitleValue === '') {
            parentLI.children('.hoverinformation').val(manualAddition);
        } else {
            parentLI.children('.hoverinformation').val(imageTitleValue + ',' + manualAddition);
        }


        $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('hide');
        removeclasses()



    });
```

Function removeclass

```
function removeclasses() {
       //Removing preselect class from all the div's when close button or add brand button is clicked.

       a = $('div .outerdiv').removeClass('preselect');
       selectedImageSRC = "";
       console.log(a);

    }
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d2cuhL6e/)

I know this is a very long post.Sorry for that but I have tried to explain each and every thing which I encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem in your code,

Your click event called more than once on click on second add image button **+** option.

```
$(document).on("click", ".addmorebrands", function() {
        parentLI = $(this).closest('li');
        $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show');
        $('#exampleModalCenter img').click(function(){
        parentdiv = $(this).closest('div.outerdiv');
        if (parentdiv.hasClass('preselect')) {                     //this if is executed in 2, 4, 5 time of code 

            parentdiv.removeClass('preselect');
            selectedImageSRC = selectedImageSRC.replace($(this).attr('src'),"");
            selectedImageSRC = trimChar(selectedImageSRC, ',');
            selectedImageSRC = (selectedImageSRC.replace(/,,/g , ","));
            console.log("In remove");
            console.log(selectedImageSRC);
            console.log("Parent Div in remove");
            console.log(parentdiv);
        }else {    //at same time (2, 4, 6 time of code execution) this else also get executed

            parentdiv.addClass('preselect');

            if (selectedImageSRC === '') {

                selectedImageSRC += $(this).attr('src');

            } else {

                selectedImageSRC += ',' + $(this).attr('src');
            }

            console.log("In add");
            console.log(selectedImageSRC);
            console.log("Parent Div in Add");
            console.log(parentdiv);
        }     

    });
});
```

This code should be like follow.

```
   $(document).on("click", ".addmorebrands", function() {
        parentLI = $(this).closest('li');
        $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show');
    });

    $('#exampleModalCenter img').click(function(){
        parentdiv = $(this).closest('div.outerdiv');
        if (parentdiv.hasClass('preselect')) {

            parentdiv.removeClass('preselect');
            selectedImageSRC = selectedImageSRC.replace($(this).attr('src'),"");
            selectedImageSRC = trimChar(selectedImageSRC, ',');
            selectedImageSRC = (selectedImageSRC.replace(/,,/g , ","));
            console.log("In remove");
            console.log(selectedImageSRC);
            console.log("Parent Div in remove");
            console.log(parentdiv);
        }else {

            parentdiv.addClass('preselect');

            if (selectedImageSRC === '') {

                selectedImageSRC += $(this).attr('src');

            } else {

                selectedImageSRC += ',' + $(this).attr('src');
            }

            console.log("In add");
            console.log(selectedImageSRC);
            console.log("Parent Div in Add");
            console.log(parentdiv);
        }     
});
```

Comment: There is other problem as well.When I dont select any image and click  `Add Image` button a blank image gets added.How can I fix that

Comment: @NewBie That you can validate before adding image

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: But exactly what was happening when I clicked `+` button for second time.I have not got that

Comment: When you click first time it works, second time it select the image but again js execute second click at same time so image get deselected, for third click select, deselect and finally selected, so multiple click events get executed on model image and it was creating problem. because you are everytime binding the click event on click on + sign